# Printing to CSV causes a space between every character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pycharm, watson

I am trying to print to CSV with Python3.6. When I print in console, it looks fine, but when I try to print to CSV, it prints `l i k e | | t h i s`.

i.e with spaces between each char, and | between each space.

I am calling the translate function [here.](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/#translate)

Sample response :

```
{
  "translations": [{
    "translation": "Hola"
  }],
  "word_count": 1,
  "character_count": 5
}
```

Here are the relevant extracts :

```
with open('C:\\Users\\SimonTheKing\\Desktop\\file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)


    # Print the contents
    for x in range(len(first_column)): #iterates over every row in an xlsx
        translation = language_translator.translate(
            model_id='123',
            text=first_column[x].value #reads from openpyxl xlsx
        )
        print(translation) #prints as expected
        spamwriter.writerow(translation) #prints a space between every char
```

Can anyone offer some guidance please ?

Comment: "Simon the King" might want to look at that `delimiter=' '`

Comment: @Mawg Oh god, that's embarrassing. It won't let me set it to nothing though, what can I set it to?

Comment: Perhaps a comma? Try omitting it all together (and maybe changing `quotechar` to a comma)?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Comment: Try `spamwriter.writerow([translation])`.

Answer (score 4):

Writerow takes an iterable as an argument, so when you give it single row string, it treats the string as an iterable and writes it with the standard space(delimiter set earlier) between each element.

You will need to either set the row to a list  with [translation] or give it a list.

Comment: wonderful, what a clever lib. give me so many spaces